# How do I filter a list of records based on the count of one of their associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have Users and Tasks associated with those Users (belongs to). I would like to get a count of Users with less than 5 tasks associated with them. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if there's an easy way of doing this, but this should work:

```
User.joins(:tasks).select("users.*, count(*) as task_count").having("task_count < 5").group(:id)
```

**EDIT**: The above only returns instances of User that have at least one associated task.

What you want is:

```
User.joins("LEFT JOIN tasks ON tasks.user_id = users.id").select("users.*, IFNULL(count(tasks.id), 0) AS task_count").having("task_count < 5").group(:id)
```

But the better solution is probably to just add a counter_cache to your User model.

Comment: I am not certain but I don't think this is working. It is giving me a number that I am fairly certain cannot be correct. We have about 10,000 users and when I change this to find users with less than 100 tasks...it tells me there are about 2,000. However, the average number of tasks per user is 2.2...so how can that be correct? EDIT: Then when I do users with greater than 100 tasks, it says 82...for a total of MUCH less than our 10,000 users base.

Comment: Sorry about that. I edited my answer to better fit your question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this works pre 1.9.2 but:

```
User.where(Task.count > 5).count
```

Comment: I'm on 1.8.7 and this didn't work. Gave me: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)